# How to move only *.java files with python?

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I have such dir tree:

> ```
> dir1
>  - dir2
>  - dir3
>  - file1.java
>  - file2.java
>  - file3.cpp
> ```

and I want to move only *.java files to brand new directory called 'java_files' in current directory. How to make it? I read shutil doc but ...

This:

```
def moveFiles() :
    source = "."
    destination = "java_files"
    if os.path.isfile(source):
        shutil.move(source, destination)
```

doesn't work at all ...

**I don't want to use shells 'mv' instead !**

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
def moveFiles() :
    source = "."
    destination = "java_files"
    dirList = os.listdir(source)
    for fname in  dirList:
        if fname.endswith(".java") :
            shutil.move(source, destination)
```

but it gives:

```
File "test.py", line 95, in <module>
 main()   File "test.py", line 91, in main
 moveFils()   File "test.py", line 82, in move
 shutil.move(source, destination)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 295, in move
 raise Error, "Cannot move a directory '%s' into itself '%s'." % (src, dst) shutil.Error:Cannot move a directory '.' into itself 'java_files'.
```

Comment: But what? Are you unable to write a check if the file name ends with .java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of cases, I use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) (which accepts wildcards and regular expressions)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import shutil
import os

source="."
destination = "/tmp/newDestination/"

if not(os.path.exists(destination)):
    os.makedirs(destination)
elif not(os.path.isdir(destination)):
    raise OSError("Kabooom! The destination %s exists, but is not a directory" % destination)

for javaFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(source, "*.java")):
    if os.path.isfile(javaFile):
        shutil.move(os.path.abspath(javaFile), destination)
```

Comment: your code, : http://pastie.org/private/olcozc9hkofwwicul0wvg gives me this: http://pastie.org/private/1layu7aoa5tvdrmlmvzxxw

Comment: when I have as `source="."` and as `destination="./java_files"`  the code you gave creates only a FILE called `java_files` ...

Comment: That's because java_files is not a directory, is it? (or at least doesn't exist)... It's behaving as a mv foo /tmp/bar If bar doesn't exist, it'll move the *file* foo to a *file* called bar in /tmp/, whereas if **bar** exists and it's a directory, it'll put the file **foo** into the bar directory. I'll be right back **:D**

Comment: thanks for the answer! Is that mean that I have to create `java_files` dir first? ok, no prob!:)

Comment: my code looks like that now: http://pastie.org/private/kl2tnv4wyiczy8afmhzka and it's working perfectly, thanks! ;* is that possible, to move to `java_files` also `dir2` and `dir3` from my dir tree? How to do it?

Comment: Shutil moves directories too. Remove the check for isfile and make the for iterate through the directories you want to move as well. You have many ways. Here's one:  *for javaFile in list(thingToMove for thingToMove in ["dir1", "dir2"] + glob.glob(os.path.join(source, "*.java"))):*

Comment: my whole code: http://pastie.org/private/o7o6nvhqp6operqyeb7ew its finally good now:)) Thank you, thank you, thank you! ;*

Comment: Then feel free to mark this as the "accepted answer"... I'm a [unsuccessful so far] reputation-sucker **:D** And it'll help you too!. I'll up your reputation and people tend to help more to people with a high "acceptance" percentage (or rate) **:)** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

```
if source.endswith('.java'):
    # do copy or move file
```

Comment: if os.path.isfile(fname) and fname.endswith('.java'):

Comment: Nobody can guess what you have done in addition - unless you provide the right code

Comment: @Maulwurfn: heres my whole code: http://pastie.org/private/olcozc9hkofwwicul0wvg but it gives this: http://pastie.org/private/1layu7aoa5tvdrmlmvzxxw